# Android: How can I reference layout items outside the Main Activity?

Tags: android, layout, methods, imagebutton

My onCreate method sets the content view and sets up an image button:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);
```

}

But I want to create a method that changes the background of the ImageButton:

```
public void mUpdateBackground() {
if (backgroundPic) {
    randomImageId = R.drawable.bg1;
}
else {
    randomImageId = R.drawable.bg0;
}
mGetClickTime.setImageResource(randomImageId);
}
```

The problem is, the mUpdateBackground method doesn't know about the layout. If I declare the layout in the method it resets all the changes made programatically in the MainActivity.

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the ImageButton declaration to your Activity scope instead of your `onCreate()` method scope. Try like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{
    ImageButton mGetClickTime;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);
    }


    public void mUpdateBackground() {
        if (backgroundPic) {
            randomImageId = R.drawable.bg1;
        }
        else {
            randomImageId = R.drawable.bg0;
        }
        mGetClickTime.setImageResource(randomImageId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried that, but the mGetClickTime inside the mUpdateBackground method is showing as null, even though the one in the onCreate is showing as correctly assigned. Any ideas?

Comment: 've got it. The problem was I forgot to change ImageButton mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker); to mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker); Thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

> the mUpdateBackground method doesn't know about the layout

I am going to translate that to mean:

> the mUpdateBackground method doesn't know about the ImageButton

If that is correct, make `ImageButton mGetClickTime` be a data member of your activity, instead of a local variable within `onCreate()`, and have `mUpdateBackground()` be a method on that same activity.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried that, but the mGetClickTime inside the mUpdateBackground method is showing as null, even though the one in the onCreate is showing as correctly assigned. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I've just reread that. Do you mean set the ImageButton mGetClickTime just after the class is defined but before the onCreate? Does that make it a field variable?

Comment: I've got it. The problem was I forgot to change   ImageButton mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);
to   mGetClickTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clicker);

Comment: Challange for CommonsWare:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601902/any-alternate-method-for-class-casting    Same but extented problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585172/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-resume-activity-packagename-classname