# Any Alternate method for Class Casting

Tags: android, devise, android-tabhost, classcastexception, android-tabs

Following statement is not executing on some devices.

```
AddEvent act1 = (AddEvent) getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
```

Is there any alternate method for above statement. On some devices it works fine but on other devices it gives exception.

[image: Click here... Yellow text shows exception]

**Edit:** My application is developed in tab. OnActivity results is used for getting picture from camera activity. Dont know where the resides but when I puts the above statement in try catch then no force close occurs and exception is shown there.

Comment: What do you cast in onActivityResult ?

Comment: Please send your stack traces by text, your screenshot is hard to read and stack over flow doesn't benefit from the ad for micro$oft (lower left corner).

Comment: @Snicolas please save image then it will be clear. Sorry to add screenshot as i was unable to copy paste whole logcat

Comment: but why this happening in some devices only. As its is working fine on HTC wildfire but crashes on Sony Xperia miro and Samsung tab.

Comment: @VarunVishnoi , to copy logcat right click on the first line of the stack trace and "find similar message" then copy stack the stack trace. Or, on command line, use adb logcat and copy your stack trace.

Comment: @Snicolas thanks :) next time sure.

Comment: You should provide what versions of android your test devices are running.

Comment: We might also be able to determine what the current problem is if you could tell us what your activity heirarchy is in your tabs- this hasn't got anything to do with inheritance- I mean which activity is parent of which in the tab group.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not really with the casting, but the assumption that the Object returned by `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()` is of type `AddEvent`. It would be difficult to say in what scenario does the `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()` return an Object that is of not the AddEvent type without looking at your implementation.

The following piece of code will check if the returned Object is indeed of type `AddEvent`:

```
if(getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity() instanceof AddEvent){
    AddEvent act1 = (AddEvent) getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
}
```

But in your case, it is recommended to check in what scenario does the `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity()` return an instance of `fable.eventippo.Home` as against `fable.eventippo.AddEvent`.

Comment: but why this happening in some devices only. As its is working fine on HTC wildfire but crashes on Sony Xperia miro and Samsung tab.

Comment: by using instanceof I am able to see on which device it is working or not... But how to implement on unsupportive devices. Means how to forcefully create the instance of class.

Comment: You cannot apply *force* to create an instance of something that you expect, by casting. Moreover, `ActivityGroup` and `LocalActivityManager` are deprecated. Use `Fragment` and `FragmentManager` API instead. You can use the support library (compatibility package) to support older platforms.

Comment: I cant change the whole code now... where i ca find the support library to support older platforms?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where do you write this line but logcat output says: You are trying to cast `Home` Activity into `AddEvent` and this is why its giving you `ClassCastException`.

FYI, `getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();` is returning `Home`.

Comment: but why this happening in some devices only. As its is working fine on HTC wildfire but crashes on Sony Xperia miro and Samsung tab.